# Nested List Item reflecting type error

Tags: wpf, xml-serialization

I have a model that contain variables and a list of another class instance..
here models:

```
public class patient
    {
        [XmlElement("firstname")]    
        public string name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("lastname")] 
        public string surname { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("age")]
        public int age { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("gender")] 
        public string gender { get; set; }
        [XmlArray("exams"), XmlArrayItem(typeof(exam), ElementName = "exam")]
        public List<exam> exam { get; set; }

    }
    public class exam
    {
        [XmlElement("id")]
        public string id { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "date", DataType = "DateTime")]
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("comment")] 
        public string comment { get; set; }
    }







List<exam> examsLocal = new List<exam>(){ 
                new exam{ id = "id of patient 1",  date = DateTime.Now,  comment = "coomment exam1" },
            };
        List<patient> overview = new List<patient>();
        try
        {
            var b = new List<patient>()
            { 
                new patient{ name = "name of patient 1", surname = "surname of patient 1", gender = "Female", age = 31, exam=examsLocal },
            };
            var writer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(List<patient>));//throw exception
```

the line throws exceptions **works fine if I delete 'exam=examsLocal' varible from List..**

What is the correct way of serialize nested List items

Answer (score 0):

Update your class definition of `exam` to be looks like:
remove the DataType of Date Property because the System.DateTime not allowed in Xml Serialization:

```
public class exam
{
  [XmlElement("id")]
  public string id { get; set; }
  [XmlElement(ElementName = "date")]
  public DateTime date { get; set; }
  [XmlElement("comment")]
  public string comment { get; set; }
}
```

And update the Property declaration in `patiant` class:

```
 [XmlArray("exams"), XmlArrayItem(typeof(exam), ElementName = "exams")]
    public List<exam> exams { get; set; }
```